# Selenium Test Repeat/Toggle

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a test in Selenium IDE with Flow Control which submits a form and repeats the process with label start until I stop the app.
I have exported my code into python WebDriver.
Unfortunately my test only runs once.
How can I duplicate this process on python.

```
        class Buy(unittest.TestCase):
            def setUp(self):
                self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
                self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
                self.base_url = "https://test.mydomain.com"

            def test_buy(self):
                driver = self.driver
                driver.get(self.base_url + "/Form")
                Select(driver.find_element_by_id("DropDownOne")).select_by_visible_text("BLUE")
                Select(driver.find_element_by_id("DropDownTwo")).select_by_visible_text("LIGHT")
                driver.find_element_by_id("Quantity").send_keys("10")
                driver.find_element_by_id("Button").click()
```

Comment: In you code create a recursive function using while loop example:- while(result!==3){} ... means there is some variable result and if it's value is not = 3 then the while loop keep running that function.. you need to add more condtion in it in case you require certain intervals only ...

Comment: So i would contain my code inside the while loop? I dont need any other function just to have it repeat until i close the browser

Edit: Added code on post

Comment: Yes you need to add your part of code in while loop which you want to repeat again and again

Comment: It's depend on your condition in while loop .. Can you add your code which you tried yet